# nvidia-xconfig not found

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

I have a computer that after installing Ubuntu 12.10, updating it and then trying to install any of the available versions of the Nvidia drivers will not install the `nvidia-xconfig` file (Which comes with the `nvidia-settings` package).

I have actually tried the 304, 306, 310 series and even installed the Xorg Edgers PPA for the 313 series. All of them with no luck.

The `nvidia-current` package installs fine and configures itself fine as a module for the particular kernel (I had previously install the headers package for this to work), but when I install the `nvidia-settings` package via the terminal I get a warning:

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/nvidia-settings/ld.so.conf because link group nvidia_settings_conf is broken
```

If I do a purge and try to install it again, the warning is gone, but if I reinstall it the warning appears. Apart from this warning, the nvidia driver is not detected and instead of going to nouveau, it jumps to vesa which gives me for an Nvidia Geforce 560 TI a resolution of 640x480.

So why is this not installing correctly and what does the warning mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion why don't you look at the documentation about your adapter and see what the supported output is, and then load this applet and see if that resolution is supported?

I for one got stuck on the driver support when I first fooled with Ubuntu, the native driver under analysis probably runs smoother, this will verify what resolutions are supported

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/resapplet/

Do a google search:
NVIDIA Optimus Hints At Better Support To Linux After Linus’ Middle Finger